# How to use AWS::LanguageExtensions transform with Serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework

To be able to use conditionals in DeletionPolicy you have to use the [AWS::LanguageExtensions transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/function-refs-in-policy-attributes.html). How would I add this to a Serverless template yaml-file?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions` under the `resources` section of the Template file like so:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  ...

functions:
  myLambda:
    handler: MyLambda.handler
  ...


resources:

  Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions

  Resources:

    MySecret:
      Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
      Properties:
        SecretString:
          Fn::ToJsonString:
            SECRET1: Value1
            SECRET2: Value2
```